# Passing naming arguments/parameters between shell functions (existing in multiple shell scripts) and finally to python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that is expecting 1, 2 or 3 arguments:

```
--name - mandatory
--max  - optional
--min  - optional
```

I have a function in bash script that calls the python script:

script_1

```
filter() {
  .../python3 -E filtered_as.pyc --name $1 --min $2 --max $3
```

Other bash scripts can call the filter function:

script_2

```
filter NAME_DEW 42 | while read id; do
.............
```

What, I want:

- instead of passing $1, $2 I want to pass named arguments, the same as expected in python script (from the shell script to the other shell script, from shell script to python.
- work with optional arguments:

  - can be all 3
  - can be just name
  - can be name and min or max (2)

Also because I have 2 optional arguments, I need named arguments to know which one is passed.

Comment: Quotes matter. `--name "$1" --min "$2" --max "$3"`, etc.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm not sure your question is currently answerable. "What [you] want" requires restructuring your data formats, but you're providing those formats as immutable. Sure, you can make `filter` take `name=NAME_DEW min=42` instead of `NAME_DW 42`, but that's not really an answer because I don't see a real _question_ here: I don't think you're ever describing a narrow, specific technical problem you need solved before you can do that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can restructure data formatting if is necessary, I can change both shelll and python scripts. The issue is from what I see the optional ones, because I don't know if min or max is passed.

Comment: That's why I suggested switching from `42` to `min=42` or `max=42` as your input format. (Or `min:42` / `max:42`, the specific sigil doesn't matter). But again, that's a design issue more than a technical problem; I don't know what technical problem you came to get our help with.

Comment: Please read [ask]. There's no question here, and the problem you're describing is quite broad (as Charles is saying). For background info, see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) But if it helps, why do you want to handle the arguments in Bash at all? Why not just pass all arguments through to the Python script (like `... filtered_as.pyc "$@"`), which is presumably using `argparse` or something similar, which is way more powerful.

Comment: BTW, if `--name` can only be provided as a flag, not a positional argument, that's a weird choice, but you could easily work around it with something like `filtered_as.pyc --name "$@"`.

Comment: Why don't you make the function take arguments in the same format as the script? Then you just do `python3 -E filtered_as.pyc "$@"` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is making a lot of guesses at what you mean by your question, because that question isn't detailed enough to answer otherwise.

Assuming you're asking how to use named prefixes to control whether arguments taken from stdin are `min` or `max`, ore way to do that might look like:

```
filter() {
  local name min= max=
  name=$1; shift || return
  while (( $# )); do
    case $1 in
      min:*) min=${1#min:};;
      max:*) max=${1#max:};;
      *)     echo "ERROR: Argument $1 should start with min: or max:" >&2;;
    esac
    shift
  done
  python3 -E filtered_as.pyc \
    --name "$name" \
    ${min:+ --min "$min"} \
    ${max:+ --max "$max"}
}
```

thereafter called as:

```
filter NAME_DEW min:42 | while read id; do ...
```